# Trying to Rxify an already asynchronous flow

Tags: android, rx-java2

I have a situation before me wherein I already have an asynchronous system in place and I'm looking to convert it to Rx streams. The flow is a part of a 3rd party library without me having the source to modify. So I'm looking to create a Rx wrapper around it.

Can't share the exact code here but to give a brief idea, I have created a singleton class which acts as a manager for this flow. In the singleton class, I have initialised the object of some class that is present in the 3rd party library. During the initialisation of this object, I have to pass a reference of a callback class in the constructor and this is the callback where the library provides responses to all the method calls asynchronously.

`Callback callback = new Callback() {

    public void onResponse(Message message) {

         // Perform action

    }

};

SomeClassInSdk clazz = new SomeClassInSdk(callback);`

What I'm looking to do here is convert this async system to Rx streams and I can't seem to figure out how to begin with it as me being a newbie to Rxjava2.

I tried to replicate the code of Retrofit RxJava2 adapter code but it has a new Callback object initialised for every observable which I can't have in my code.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Observable.fromCallable()` [Docs Link](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#fromCallable-java.util.concurrent.Callable-). You just wrap your async callback with this method and it returns an observable.

You can also use ***Single*** & ***Maybe***. Look into docs for more details:

Following is the example of using ***Single*** to convert imperative programming paradigm into Reactive.

```
public Single<String> myMethod() {
        return Single.create(new Single.OnSubscribe<String>() {
            @Override
            public void call(final SingleSubscriber<? super String> singleSubscriber) {

                myAsyncMethod(new Callback() {
                    public void success(String data) {
                        singleSubscriber.onSuccess(data); // call this upon success                        
                    }

                    public void failure(String err) {
                        singleSubscriber.onError(err);                        
                    }
                })
            }
        });
    }
```